# Office/Business notebook for C# development

Tags: windows, development, web-development

I'm going to get me a new Hardware/Software-system for my development.
The project I'm currently in has about 60 sub-projects which are of type WPF, Server/Client, WCF, Rest-API and simple class-libraries.

My (hardware) needs are the following:

- 14 or 15 inch display
- minimum 8GB RAM
- i5/i7 processor
- 500GB HDD (may also be an hybrid drive with 8GB SSD)
- 27 inch Monitor (Wide Quad HD / 2560 x 1440) [Dell @amazon](http://www.amazon.de/Dell-210-ADZG-U2515H-Monitor/dp/B00P6O3YYO/ref=pd_sim_sbs_147_1?ie=UTF8&dpID=41Getv2arAL&dpSrc=sims&preST=_AC_UL160_SR160%2C160_&refRID=0PTJY6ZX5942RQH6K3CF)
- USB-Docking-Station [DockingStation @amazon](http://www.amazon.de/Plugable-Universelle-Dockingstation-Videoausg%C3%A4ngen-Schnittstelle/dp/B00GQ3685Q/ref=sr_1_2?s=computers&ie=UTF8&qid=1453966268&sr=1-2&keywords=usb%20dockingstation%202560%20%201440)

My (software)-requirements are the following:

- Windows 10 Pro x64
- Visual Studio 2015 Pro + latest ReSharper (currently V10)
- latest Office (Standard)

I'm going to spend at maximum 2,500€. What would be a good choice?
Can I handle a second monitor with this Docking-Station? One directly connected to the laptop and one over the dock?

I've looking for something like [this @amazon](http://www.amazon.de/Asus-Zenbook-UX303UA-R4156T-Notebook-GeForce/dp/B017U9HZE2/ref=sr_1_3?s=computers&ie=UTF8&qid=1453966495&sr=1-3&keywords=notebook), but I'm pretty sure that I do need some additional old-school HDD (maybe external) to not crash the SSD with all my builds.